# What is jQuery.noConflict? Explain difference between the below code? And it's benefits

Tags: javascript, jquery

### What is the main difference between the two cases

**#1 case**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("div").hide();
});
```

**#2 case**

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
$j(document).ready(function(){
   $j("div").hide();
});
```

Please explain with these code.

Also describe the **benefits of `jQuery.noConflict();`.**

Comment: As other client side libraries like MooTools, Prototype can be used with jQuery and they also use ``` $() ``` as their global function and to define variables. This situation creates conflict as ``` $() ``` is used by jQuery and other library as their global function. To overcome from such situations, jQuery has introduced ``` jQuery.noConflict() ``` .

Comment: Please describe in detail.

Comment: Did you try reading the [noConflict() docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) before asking? What part don't you understand?

Comment: Please describe Benefits

Comment: Again...what part of the docs are not clear?

Comment: use multiple versions of the jQuery library on the same page

Comment: Is only benefits

Comment: Really sounds like you haven't bothered to read the docs ***thoroughly***. What specific problem are you trying to solve that are not explained there? The different approaches and reasons are explained in the docs yet you have yet to identify which part is unclear to you

Comment: I like to know the benefits about jQuery noConflict

Comment: You have said that many times now without ever expanding on what is unclear in the documentation! You aren't going to get any clearer explanations than what has allready been given by asking the same thing over and over without more question detail. How many times do we need to ask what part you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call jQuery.noConflict(). It returns the jQuery object `$` to whatever `$` used to contain. Which can be another version of jQuery or another library/object. You can assign your different version of jQuery to a variable so that $ gets restored to what it used to be which the rest of the javascript files depend on because newer versions of jquery have deleted outdated functions. Functions that the older scripts depend on.

So for example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    // $ contains jquery version 2.1.1

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    
    // $ now contains jquery version 3.1.1

    var jQueryVersion3 = $.noConflict();

    // $ now contains jquery version 2.1.1
    // jQueryVersion3 contains jquery version 3.1.1

    jQueryVersion3(document).ready(function()
    {
        jQueryVersion3("body").append("<div>Hello world</div>");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Not always another version loaded. Most common use case is prevent `$` conflicts alone

Comment: @charlietfl yes, it restores $ to whatever it was before. jQuery object or not. When jQuery first initializes. It saves a copy of the $ value within itself for the noConflict() call. Before overwriting it.

Comment: Please describe about benefits.

Comment: @RayeesAC if you include jQuery and it overwrites $. And you have another library that was using the $ variable. Then every call that the other library makes with $ will throw an error because its not the object it was expecting.